# Wordpress WP_DEBUG not showing errors

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, wamp

My Current configuration is

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE) ;
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', TRUE );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', TRUE );
```

php errors are showing without any problem but **wordpress errors like deprecated function calls are not showing**. **But debug logging to file works**, wordpress errors are logging to file in wp-content. I tried somewhat all solutions but not working. I am adding the links of solutions I tried. The funny thing is this is not working in **Local Server (WAMP)**, but working perfectly in Live Server.
I referred these links and tried but didn't worked for me.
1. [define('WP_DEBUG', true); not show errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266155/definewp-debug-true-not-show-errors)
2. [Debug logs at wordpress not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325708/debug-logs-at-wordpress-not-working)
3. [Wordpress Debugging does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922464/wordpress-debugging-does-not-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [define('WP\_DEBUG', true); not show errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266155/definewp-debug-true-not-show-errors)

Comment: No, I have mentioned this link in my question already. I have referred and tried that solution but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Try plugins like wordpress.org/plugins/issues-tracker or do everything as described in the documentation wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress

Answer (score 2):

I Found the actual problem that doesn't show debug errors is because of using **Query Monitor plugin**. Also **Debug bar plugin** too disable default wordpress debug errors. Just Deactivated this plugin and debug errors are displaying now.

> **Cheers!**